# Please explain the man page of command mv

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I understand if I `mv foo.file boo.file`, I just rename foo.file to boo.file, and if I `mv dir1/foo.file dir2/boo.file`, I delete dir1/foo.file and make a copy of that to dir2 and rename it as boo.file. But I was looking at the man page here:

```
NAME
     mv -- move files

SYNOPSIS
     mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
     mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

DESCRIPTION
     In its first form, the mv utility renames the file named by the source
     operand to the destination path named by the target operand.  This form
     is assumed when the last operand does not name an already existing direc-
     tory.

     In its second form, mv moves each file named by a source operand to a
     destination file in the existing directory named by the directory oper-
     and.  The destination path for each operand is the pathname produced by
     the concatenation of the last operand, a slash, and the final pathname
     component of the named file.
```

I have 2 questions:
1. I know that "..." means repeatable argument, so what if I do `mv dir1/foo.file dir2/boo.file dir3/woo.file`, what happens?
2. I don't quite get the second paragraph about the second form about "`The destination path for each operand is the pathname produced by the concatenation of the last operand, a slash, and the final pathname component of the named file.`", what does "for each operand" and "the concatenation of the last operand, a slash, and the final pathname component of the named file" means?

Sorry I know they are silly questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mv`has two forms:

first:

```
mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
```

second:

```
mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

---

To answer your first question, in the **second** form, you have "..." that means that you can have more than one source , but only one destination that specifically is a directory so you can do this:

```
mv 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt new
```

and it will move the three files to a previously created directory called `new`.

---

To answer your second question, it simply says that the new path for moved files will be the directory plus the original name of the file.
The `last operand` is the destination directory and the `final pathname`is the name of the files,

Answer (score 0):

If the last argument passed to `mv` is an existing directory, it moves the earlier listed file or files into that directory. It has to be an existing directory, since otherwise trying to `mv` a single file would be unclear whether to change the name, or move into a new directory with the same file name. The language in the man page is somewhat more formal and specific than what I say here (and more of a direct explanation of what the code does), in an effort to be exactly precise for any questions about how `mv` might work for some odd case with unusual file or directory names.

And no, it isn't a silly question.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for clearing that up. I was really frustrated reading man page

Answer (score 0):

1. `mv` tries to move the files `dir1/foo.file` AND `dir2/boo.file` to directory `dir3/woo.file`. This fails since `dir3/woo.file` is not a directory. (you can easily try it out)
2. "for each operand" refers to the variable list of arguments (given by `...`). Since the second operation form is only valid if the last one is a directory, "the concatenation of the last operand, a slash, and the final pathname component of the named file" means `mv` just concatenates (joins) the targetDirectory(which is the last argument)+"/"+the filename of the corresponding argument (so, without the folder structure [link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename)). 
   I.e., "the final pathname component of the named file" of `/a/b/c` is `c` and of `b/e/r` is `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly:
The command `mv` moves and/or renames files and/or directory. **It doesn't copy and delete them** unless the target directory is on a different filesystem. (Not all implementations of `mv` may support that.)

1. If `file.a` and `file.b` are files or directories and `c` doesn't exists or it is not a directory or a link to a directory, the command

   ```
   mv file.a file.b c
   ```

   will give you an error and nothing more :)
2. It means simply that the command

   ```
   mv dir1/file.a dir2/file.b C
   ```

   is the same that to write:

   ```
   mv dir1/file.a  C/file.a
   mv dir2/file.b  C/file.b
   ```

---

With more words:

The command `mv` *moves (renames) files* and, at least in my system, has **three** forms:

> mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
>     mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
>     mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

1. When you want to move **and/or** rename a single file

   - `mv file.a file.b` or `mv dir.a dir.b`   **#Simple Renaming.**
     It renames the `file.a` with a new name `file.b`.
     Note: It is the same file. If you perform a `ls -i file.a` before and `ls -i file.b` you will notice the **same number of inode**. It means that normally **you are not copying the file and deleting the old one**.
   - `mv OldPath/file.a NewPath/file.a`   **# Simple moving**
     Again the file before and after has the same inode. The same if you are moving/renaming  a directory.
   - `mv OldPath/file.a NewPath/file.b`   **# Moving and renaming**
     It moves and rename the file from the OldPath to NewPath. Again the file before and after has the same inode. The same if you are moving/renaming  a directory.
2. When you want to move many files to a destination directory. E.g.

   ```
   mv dir1/file1 dir2/file2 ... /long/path/to/dir
   ```

   is like to write:

   ```
   mv dir1/file1 /long/path/to/dir/file1
   mv dir2/file2 /long/path/to/dir/file2
   ```
3. You specify `-t` and the destination directory before the list of the file to be moved.
   E.g. `mv -t /long/path/to/dir file1 file2 ...`

   > -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
   >       move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY

---

BTW *No question is a silly question only the answers can be silly* :-)